# Add a callback closure to a class constructor

Tags: php, callback

I have a class that someone else wrote. It does a lot of things for me, and one thing it does for me is it makes requests to an external service.

```
public function makeRequest() {
   ...bunch of curl stuff here
}
```

So what I wanted to do is modify the constructor of the class so that I could pass in a function, and the function could get called after the curl stuff. I come from a javascript background so I'm definitely doing this the wrong way, but this is what I did:

```
private $requestLogger;
public function __construct(...other variables, $requestLogger = null) {
   if ($requestLogger) {
      $this->requestLogger = $requestLogger;
   }
}

public function makeRequest() {
   ...bunch of curl stuff here
   if ($this->requestLogger) {
            $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
            $this->requestLogger($curlInfo['url'], $curlInfo['http_code'], $request, $response);
   }
}
```

And that when when I make a new instance, I can do it like this

```
$client = new ApiClient(..., function($url, $responseCode, $requestText, $responseText){
   // do whatever i want here
});
```

However, this hasn't worked. I get this message: `500: Call to undefined method ApiClient::requestLogger()`

How do I set myself up to pass a callback function to this class?

Comment: Not sure where I saw it, but you should be able to do `($this->requestLogger)(.......`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do: `$this->requestLogger(...)`, PHP thinks you're trying to call a class method called `requestLogger()`.

If you want to call a function in a class property, you can use [call_user_func_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). Something like this:

```
call_user_func_array($this->requestLogger, [
    $curlInfo['url'], 
    $curlInfo['http_code'], 
    $request, 
    $response
]);
```

A tip, before trying to call it, make sure it contains something that's callable and not just empty:

```
if (is_callable($this->requestLogger)) {
    call_user_func_array(...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just before you posted this, i tried `call_user_func($this->requestLogger, $curlInfo['url'], $curlInfo['http_code'], json_encode($parameters), $response);` and it worked.

Comment: @TKoL - Yes, it does the same thing. I tend to use this out of habit because you then could define an array with all the params so they could be more dynamic. But PHP now have the argument unpacking (splat operator) since PHP 5.6, which would solve that either way.